Conditional Probability: Making the right assumptions

A smoker is 23 times as likely as a non-smoker to develop lung cancer, and 21.6% men in U.S smoke. Find the probability that a person is a smoker, if he develops cancer.

I came to the same answer as on this page, but I have a question about my methodology.
I used P(L|S) = 23/24, where P(L) = probability of lung cancer, and P(S) = probability of smoker. Is this correct, or does it make an incorrect assumption of the probability of getting cancer given that they smoke?

I'm guessing because $\frac{23}{24}=23\times \frac{1}{24}$.

And yes, your calculations look good to me, but I am no statistician.

All that we know in this problem is that $P(L \mid S) = 23 \cdot P(L \mid \neg S)$; we do not have enough information to determine $P(L \mid S)$. So assuming $P(L \mid S) = \frac{23}{24}$ is not a valid assumption. (I assume you were trying to have $P(L \mid S) + P(L \mid \neg S) = 1$, but this is not necessarily true, unlike the similar-looking identity $P(L \mid S) + P(\neg L \mid S) = 1$.)
What saves the day is that, in using Bayes' rule to compute $P(S \mid L)$, we do not need to know the probabilities $P(L \mid S)$ and $P(L \mid \neg S)$ individually; their ratio (which is $23:1$) is all we need to know. We get the same answer if we use:

$P(L \mid S) = \frac{23}{24}$ and $P(L \mid \neg S) = \frac1{24}$;
$P(L \mid S) = 0.23$ and $P(L \mid \neg S) = 0.01$;
$P(L \mid S) = 23x$ and $P(L \mid \neg S) = x$, where the unknown parameter $x$ will cancel out in the end.

So the invalid assumption is assuming too much, but it doesn't turn out to matter.
To see why, here's what happens if we use $P(L \mid S) = 23x$ and $P(L \mid \neg S) = x$. We end up with $$P(L) = P(L \mid S) P(S) + P(L \mid \neg S) P(\neg S) = 23x \cdot 0.216 + x \cdot 0.784 = 5.752x.$$ Therefore $$P(S \mid L) = \frac{P(L \mid S) P(S)}{P(L)} = \frac{23x \cdot 0.216}{5.752x} = \frac{4.968x}{5.752x} \approx 0.8637.$$
The $x$ cancels, so we know that we will get the same answer no matter what $x$ is; in particular, we will get the correct answer if we set $x = \frac1{24}$, even though there is no reason why $x$ should be $\frac1{24}$ or anything else in particular.
We could even do the calculations with the nonsensical "probabilities" $P(L \mid S) = 23$ and $P(L \mid \neg S) = 1$. These do not make any sense, but we will still get the right answer.
